# Finding part of string and extracting data between delimiter using BigQuery SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, split, google-bigquery, substring

I have a column like this:

| String_to_Extract |
| --- |
| A~S1_B~S2_C~S11 |
| A~S1_B~S3_C~S12 |
| C~S13_A~S11_B~S4 |

The part before the "~" should be the column name. The part after the "~" should be the row value.   This is separated by a "_" . Therefore, the result should look like this:

| String_to_Extract | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A~S1_B~S2_C~S11 | S1 | S2 | S11 |
| A~S1_B~S3_C~S12 | S1 | S3 | S12 |
| C~S13_A~S11_B~S4 | S11 | S4 | S13 |

Here is my approach:

```
SELECT
String_to_Extract,
SUBSTRING(String_to_Extract, INSTR(Advertiser, "A~")+2, ?) AS A,
SUBSTRING(String_to_Extract, INSTR(Advertiser, "B~")+2, ?) AS B,
SUBSTRING(String_to_Extract, INSTR(Advertiser, "C~")+2, ?) AS C,
From Table
```

How do I get the part between the ~ and next _ for each column?

Would be glad about help!

Comment: Your expected output for `C~S13_A~S1_B~S4` appears to be off in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach uses `REGEXP_EXTRACT`:

```sql
SELECT
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(String_to_Extract, r"(?:^|_)A~([^_]+)") AS A,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(String_to_Extract, r"(?:^|_)B~([^_]+)") AS B,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(String_to_Extract, r"(?:^|_)C~([^~]+)") AS C
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However, the order of the parameters could change or more could be added. Therefore, it would be useful to first search for the respective identifiers (A~, B~, C~, D~, .....) I guess.

Comment: I get it.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: One more question on this. My delimiter now changed from ~ to |.  So the string looks like: A|S1_B|S2_C|S11. The problem is that it will be identified as an OR operator. How can I handle this?

Comment: @MichaHein You need to _escape_ the pipe, e.g. for the `A` value use: `(?:^|_)A\|([^_]+)`

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach (BigQuery)

```
select * from (
  select String_to_Extract, col_val[offset(0)] as col, col_val[offset(1)] as val
  from your_table, unnest(split(String_to_Extract, '_')) kv,
  unnest([struct(split(kv, '~') as col_val)])
)
pivot (any_value(val) for col in ('A', 'B', 'C'))
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this approach which orders the splitted item first and then picks the values:

```sql
select 
   split(ordered[safe_offset(0)], '~')[safe_offset(1)] as A,
   split(ordered[safe_offset(1)], '~')[safe_offset(1)] as B,
   split(ordered[safe_offset(2)], '~')[safe_offset(1)] as C
 from (
    select 
        array(select _ from unnest(split(Advertiser, '_') ) as _ order by 1) as ordered
    from dataset.table
)
```